# How is rand properly used in Win64 NASM Assembly?

Tags: assembly, random, 64-bit, nasm

I'm not sure how to get a random number within a specific range in x64 Assembly.
Most of the examples I've seen on SO and around the web have been on Linux, so advice on how to do it on Windows would be greatly appreciated!

```
default rel

extern printf
extern scanf
extern rand

section .rdata  ;; constants
    prompt: db "What is your guess? (Answer is: %d) ", 0
    congrats: db "You guessed it!", 10, 0

section .data   ;; mutable variables
    guess: dq 0
    target: dq 0    ; assumed constant, but technically not

section .text
    global main
main:
    stack_reserve: equ 40
    sub     rsp, stack_reserve

    ;; let's assign our random target
    ;; rand(num_target) % 100 + 1

    lea     rcx, [prompt]
    call    printf

    add     rsp, stack_reserve
    ret
```

Comment: You'd call it the same way the compiler does, the same way you'd call any other function.  Look at MSVC -O2 asm output on https://godbolt.org/ for a function that calls it if you want to see an example.

Comment: That's very helpful! What do the `PTR` specifications mean, and is there a way to simplify statements like `QWORD PTR [rbp-16]`?

Comment: PTR is short for pointer.  In NASM, you just use `qword [rbp-16]`.  I forgot you were looking for NASM syntax; you could disassemble an object file if you need automated conversion to NASM syntax.  e.g. use Agner Fog's `objconv` disassembler which has a NASM output mode.  Or see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info for some of the differences between NASM and MASM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out:

```
;; calculate the random number
xor     rax, rax
mov     rcx, rax
call    time
mov     rcx, rax
call    srand
call    rand

;; rand = (rand % 100) + 1
xor     rdx, rdx
mov     rcx, 100
div     rcx
inc     rdx
mov     [target], rdx
mov     rcx, scan_fmt
call    printf
```